# FIltering columns satisfying abundance distribution among samples in groups in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe looking like;

```
         ColumnA ColumnB  ColumnC group
Sample1     0.05 0.00042     0.12     X
Sample2      0.2 0.00084    0.223     X
Sample3     0.04 0.00045    0.063     X
Sample4    1e-04    0.13    0.013     X
Sample5     0.03  0.0058    3e-04     Y
Sample6     0.05  0.0066  0.00021     Y
Sample7    0.006   0.022  3.2e-06     Y
Sample8    8e-04   0.101  0.00063     Y
Sample9    4e-04   2e-04 0.000233     Z
Sample10   0.008   5e-04  0.00075     Z
Sample11    0.02 8.6e-05  0.00076     Z
Sample12   0.035 4.3e-05  0.00044     Z
```

If at least 3 of the 4 samples have abundance more than 0.01 for at least one group (Columns A and C in the example above), I would like to retain that column.

Can you please help me to find a solution using dplyr package?

Thank you

Comment: So, essentially, you just want to count how many values in each column are >0.01 and then select columns where that number is >3? Does the `group` column have any relevance here?

Comment: Yes, but 3 of the 4 samples in each X, Y, and Z groups. If samples in any of the three groups satisfies that for respective column, I want to keep that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `select` + `where` to select columns dynamically, and store the names of those columns in a vector. Then use `select` on the original data set:

```r
library(dplyr)
nms <- 
  df %>% 
  # across the selected columns, check if at least 3 elements in each group are above 0.01
  summarise(across(ColumnA:ColumnC, ~ sum(.x > 0.01) >= 3), .by = group) %>% 
  # Select the columns where any of the groups satisfy the conditions and extract the names
  select(where(~ is.logical(.x) && any(.x))) %>% names()

#> nms
#> [1] "ColumnA" "ColumnC"

df %>% 
  select(all_of(nms))

#          ColumnA  ColumnC
# Sample1   0.0500 1.20e-01
# Sample2   0.2000 2.23e-01
# Sample3   0.0400 6.30e-02
# Sample4   0.0001 1.30e-02
# Sample5   0.0300 3.00e-04
# Sample6   0.0500 2.10e-04
# Sample7   0.0060 3.20e-06
# Sample8   0.0008 6.30e-04
# Sample9   0.0004 2.33e-04
# Sample10  0.0080 7.50e-04
# Sample11  0.0200 7.60e-04
# Sample12  0.0350 4.40e-04
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who are interested, a **base R** approach

```
selec <- colSums(aggregate(. ~ group, df, \(x) sum(x > 0.01) >= 3)[-1]) > 0

df[,names(selec)[selec]]
         ColumnA  ColumnC
Sample1   0.0500 1.20e-01
Sample2   0.2000 2.23e-01
Sample3   0.0400 6.30e-02
Sample4   0.0001 1.30e-02
Sample5   0.0300 3.00e-04
Sample6   0.0500 2.10e-04
Sample7   0.0060 3.20e-06
Sample8   0.0008 6.30e-04
Sample9   0.0004 2.33e-04
Sample10  0.0080 7.50e-04
Sample11  0.0200 7.60e-04
Sample12  0.0350 4.40e-04
```